# Cannot receive packet data over BullkIO port sent from Executable Device

Tags: python, redhawksdr

I want to create data on a Device and send it over a BulkIO port to a Component running inside of a Waveform on the Device. I believe this is the correct way to create data flow from hardware into a Component.

I have a usesport on the Device:

```
port_dataChar = usesport(name="dataChar",
                         repid="IDL:BULKIO/dataChar:1.0",
                         type_="data")
```

I have a providesport on the Component running on the Device:

```
port_dataChar = providesport(name="dataChar",
                             repid="IDL:BULKIO/dataChar:1.0",
                             type_="data")
```

I am able to connect these ports programatically using this python snippet:

```
comp_port = domain.devMgrs[0].devs[0].getPort('dataChar')
dev_port = domain.apps[0].comps[0].getPort('dataChar')
comp_port.connectPort(dev_port, 'ConnectionId')
```

This all works great and is very similar to how I have connected the FrontEnd 2.0 DigitalTuner ports on the same Component/Device pair. Those FE 2.0 ports work well and pass all tests.

Now, I go ahead and start the device:

```
domain.devMgrs[0].devs[0].start()
```

It is executing this code:

```
data = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c']
ts = time.time()
tstamp = BULKIO.PrecisionUTCTime(BULKIO.TCM_CPU,BULKIO.TCS_VALID,0.0,
                                 int(ts),ts - int(ts))
EOS = False
streamId = "1"
print "Sending data of length", len(data)
self.port_dataChar.pushPacket(data, tstamp, EOS, streamId)
return NOOP
```

This prints out on the Dev Mgr:

```
Sending data of length 27
Sending data of length 27
Sending data of length 27
Sending data of length 27
Sending data of length 27
Sending data of length 27
...
```

This all seems good

Then I go ahead and start the waveform:

```
wave.start()
```

It is executing this code:

```
print "Iteration number ", self.numIter 
data, T, EOS, streamID, sri, sriChanged, inputQueueFlushed = self.port_dataChar.getPacket()

if (data != None):
    print "Got data of length ", len(data)
else:
    print "Got no data, streamId ", streamID    
return NOOP
```

However, it never gets any of the packets/data from the dataChar port:

```
Iteration number 1
Got no data, streamId None
Sending data of length 27
Iteration number 2
Got no data, streamId None
Sending data of length 27
Iteration number 3
Sending data of length 27
Got no data, streamId None
Sending data of length 27
Iteration number 4
Got no data, streamId None
```

Am I doing something wrong? Is it possible to receive data over BulkIO from a Device? I am also trying to figure out how to monitor the BulkIO port(s) to figure out what is going wrong, but I cannot find out how to monitor the ports in the documentation.

I can receive data on the component in the Sandbox using this code:

```
b = sb.Component("MyComponent")
kw = sb.SRIKeyword("SOME_RF",155000000.0,'double')
keywords = [kw]
i = sb.DataSource()
data = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c']
i.connect(b)
sb.start()
i.push(data,SRIKeywords=keywords)
```

I attempted to push the SRI before the packet data with no luck:

```
keywords = []
H = BULKIO.StreamSRI(1, 0.0, 0.0, BULKIO.UNITS_TIME, 0, 0.0, 0.0, BULKIO.UNITS_NONE, 0, "1", True, keywords)
self.port_dataChar.pushSRI(H)
self.port_dataChar.pushPacket(data, tstamp, EOS, streamID)
```

UPDATE: I can now answer this question myself. The problem lies in the format being sent to pushPacket(). It should be a string instead of an array of chars to be sent over a dataChar BulkIO port. Essentially this:

```
data = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c']
self.port_dataChar.pushPacket(data, tstamp, EOS, streamId)
```

should be changed to this:

```
data = "testing123"
self.port_dataChar.pushPacket(data, tstamp, EOS, streamId)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that your pushPacket() call is causing a `CORBA.BAD_PARAM(omniORB.BAD_PARAM_WrongPythonType, CORBA.COMPLETED_NO)` exception and failing silently (using version 1.9.0 of REDHAWK). dataChar is intended to be used for character data, and it turns out that the underlying omniORBpy / BulkIO mappings are expecting a string value, and not a list of strings for the data variable. If you need to send character data from your device to your component, you should use:

```
data = "your text here"
self.port_dataChar.pushPacket(data, tstamp, EOS, streamId)
```

If your intention is simply to have BulkIO data flow from your device to your component, I would suggest using a dataFloat port.

If you want to monitor the output of your ports, the *Port Monitor* and *Data List* views in the [REDHAWK IDE](http://redhawksdr.github.io/Documentation/mainch19.html#x21-31300019.4) can be useful for debugging.